# JWT handling expiration with a database

Tags: authentication, socket.io, jwt, access-token

I've been thinking about the same problem lately and would like to know if there are any major pitfalls to my token solution:

- Set expiration to a low value (~15 minutes)
- Every generated JWT also gets added to an "issuedTokens" collection/table for each user

During JWT validation, if the expiration has passed, an "Expired" response would be returned from the server (ex. 401 w/ "Expired" in body). When the client receives this status, it should initiate a refresh process which trades an expired token for a new one.

The refresh endpoint on the server should take an expired token and perform the following:

1. Validate token (except expiration)
2. Retrieve user ID and check if token is in its issuedTokens collection
3. Issue a new JWT
4. Remove the expired token from the collection and add the new one

Upon failure of any of these steps, an Unauthorized error should be sent to client which then requires logging in again.

To prevent a never-ending build-up of issued tokens, we can set a TTL on the tokens in the issuedTokens collection. Set the TTL value to the amount of time that a login should be active for before requiring logging in again.

This approach doesn't hit the database unless you keep trying to refresh an expired token. In which case you can make use of a cached blacklist of failed tokens. This can reside next to the application itself if treated as a cache layer.

This is definitely just a work-in-progress solution that I'm about to test out. Let me know your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues I see with this approach. First of all, if I'm able to steal anyone's JWT token, I can keep geting a new ones by calling your endpoint.

[OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) for example mitigates this by requiring the client to send along client credentials when using a refresh token.
Some libraries for public clients use session cookies between client and authorization server (not the resource (API) server) to renew tokens.

The other problem is of course the collection of all JWT tokens, which is like a credentials database. If someone manages to steal this, they gain access to your application as any of your users.

Coming up with your own authentication mechanism is extremely difficult to get correct and therefore very risky.

Comment: What do you mean by 'client credentials' what information do these credentials include?

Comment: Think of client credentials as a sort of username/password for the client application itself. They identify the application instead of the user.

Comment: What happens if the hacker gets hold of the client's username/password? Can you give an example of how this might work with a web application?

Comment: With the client credentials and the refresh token, you can get a new access token from the authorization server. That is why refresh tokens are only issued to confidential (server side) clients. For public clients (SPA applications for example), the browser typically has a cookie session with the authorization server.

Comment: I'm still confused, it is a SPA I have, at the moment it uses a user login to get a token client side and uses it to access resources. Are you saying I need to store a second token (refresh token) in the client side? What is the difference between having this refresh token and access token? Couldn't a hacker just steal both the refresh token and access token too?

Comment: @amiawizard No, SPAs are public clients (they cannot hold secrets), so refresh tokens won't work. They way Google and Microsoft solved this is by creating a cookie session between the browser and auth server when the user logs in. While those cookies are valid, the SPA app can refresh tokens. When the cookies expire, the user is prompted to log in again.

Comment: Can I use only a resource server and give access tokens as well as creating a cookie session from this server to the SPA? I'm still confused, is a cookie any more secure than a token? How does having a cookie session make the application more secure, a hacker could just steal the cookie like token?

Comment: Anything can be stole, but it's a lot harder to steal secure HTTP only cookies that are only sent to the auth server which lives on a different domain than your API.